# Profile is being used in community by salesforce?

Tags: community, administration, profile, site.com, fls

I am able to see two profile related to site and user.

**Which profile is used by salesforce to provide Field level access of a object?**

First one is : 
(Open Contact having user -> View User -> Click on Profile) 
[image]

Second one is :

(Open site -> Click on public access setting {It will open different profile})
[image]

[image]

Both opens a profile, different from each other.

In both I am able to find section of FLS:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**If you're talking about a contact who has a user account (your first scenario), then the profile assigned to their user record is what controls FLS just like with any internal user.**

[Public access settings](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sites_public_access_settings.htm&type=5) control what *public users* can do on the site. Consider this the profile page for the Site for non-members. You can set the following:

> - Set the object permissions for your site. You can grant “Read” and “Create” permissions on all standard objects except products, price
>     books, and ideas; and “Read,” “Create,” “Edit,” and “Delete” on all
>     custom objects. All permissions that aren't set by default must be set
>     manually.
> - Control the visibility of custom apps. If you want to expose a custom app and its associated tabs to public users, make only that app
>     visible and make it the default to avoid exposing other pages. If any
>     of your site pages use standard Salesforce headers, other visible
>     applications may be seen by public users.
> - Set the login hours during which users can access the site.
> - Restrict the IP address ranges from which you can access the site.
> - Enable Apex controllers and methods for your site. Controllers and methods that are already associated with your site's Visualforce pages
>     are enabled by default.
> - Enable Visualforce pages for your site. Changes made here are reflected on the Site Visualforce Pages related list on the Site
>     Details page, and vice versa.